# Cost of building a list from string

Tags: python

I need to manipulate a string in python, for this I'm creating a list of characters from the string, since python strings are immutable :

```
str = 'abc'
list(str)
```

The problem is that the string can contain upto a million characters and I am not sure whether creating a list is slowing the code down or not.

What is the complexity of the above task? and is there any better alternative to manipulating strings?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string?

Comment: I need to manipulate the string, actually I'm solving this question from SPOJ [PALIN](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/)

Comment: Time complexity is O(N). Also for palindromes you don't need to build a list. Using `[::-1]` on strings should work fine.

Comment: @jamylak so is there any better alternative to manipulating strings or this is it?

Comment: @KartikAnand you don't need to build a list

Comment: @jamylak yes I'm using [::-1] only, but at some point I do need to manipulate it

Comment: @KartikAnand yes but im sure you don't need a list for that. You could give more details on what manipulation you say you need. There are many methods in the string class

Comment: @jamylak say the new palindrome is older than the last one, for eg the number is 9999, now I need to change it to 10001, for this I need manipulations.

Comment: @KartikAnand can you not just set it to the new number? Anyway you should really post this info in the question I can't comment here any further

Answer (score 4):

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but *only after that code has been identified*. It is often a mistake to make a priori judgments about what parts of a program are really critical, since *the universal experience of programmers who have been using measurement tools has been that their intuitive guesses fail*. --Donald Knuth (emphasis mine)

In other words, unless you've profiled your code and it's slow **because** you're converting your string into a list, don't worry about it - there are probably far greater gains to make elsewhere.

Comment: Your answer is really great, but it still doesnt answer about the complexity or any other better technique. Though I must say it is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you need to read string from file, modify it and then write back to file? If this so most memory efficient way will be to use mmap module and you do not need to 
build the list. Here is the example from the modules official documentation:

```
import mmap

# write a simple example file
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b"Hello Python!\n")

with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    # read content via standard file methods
    print(mm.readline())  # prints b"Hello Python!\n"
    # read content via slice notation
    print(mm[:5])  # prints b"Hello"
    # update content using slice notation;
    # note that new content must have same size
    mm[6:] = b" world!\n"
    # ... and read again using standard file methods
    mm.seek(0)
    print(mm.readline())  # prints b"Hello  world!\n"
    # close the map
    mm.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting results like this:

```
~ $ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import time
import random
length = len( str(random.random()) )
longString = ""
for x in range(1000000 / length):
  longString += str( random.random() )

a = time.time()

li = list(longString)

b = time.time()

print "Time was: " + str(b - a) + " seconds"
print "Length of list" , len(li)
print "length of string " , len(longString)
print "Sample of list: " , li[:100]

~ $ ./test.py
Time was: 0.0284309387207 seconds
Length of list 999863
length of string  999863
Sample of list:  ['0', '.', '0', '5', '3', '2', '0', '9', '3', '0' ....actually longer
```

Comment: [The `timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is better for benchmarking.